# smart_listing gem installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, smart-listing

I am new to ruby on rails and would like to use the smart_listing gem for my app.
I am following the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Sology/smart_listing) but two errors show up.

1) When I add `//= require smart_listing` to `application.js`. I get the following error: `couldn't find file 'smart_listing' with type 'application/javascript'`

2) When I include the the lines below in my Category controller

```
include SmartListing::Helper::ControllerExtensions
helper  SmartListing::Helper
```

I get the follwiing errors: `uninitialized constant CategoriesController::SmartListing`

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you restart your server after adding new gem and bundle?

Comment: I bundled but forgot to restart. Thanks! It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always restart your server after you run `bundle install` or the changes you've made (newly installed gem) won't be reflected.